# How to implement precondition for a method?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, code-contracts

I have a class

```
public class MyService  
{  
   public IList<Exception> ExList {get; private set;}

   public bool HasErrors { get { return ExList.Count > 0; } }

   public MyMethod()
   {
       ExList.Clear();
       //- do some logic ---
   }

}
```

And I want to call MyMethod() and check if errors was occured. Something like this

```
var service = new MyService();

service.MyMethod();

if(service.HasErrors)
{
    // - do some logic
}

service.MyMethod();

if(service.HasErrors)
{
    // - do some logic
}
```

But I have to write "ExList.Clear();" row manualy for every method in MyService class.
And the question is - Are any solution to avoid this?

I need something like

```
public class MyService  
{  
   public IList<Exception> ExList {get; private set;}

   public bool HasErrors { get { return ExList.Count > 0; } }

   private void Precondition()
   {
       ExList.Clear();
   }

   public MyMethod()
   {           
       //- do some logic ---
   }

}
```

And Precondition() would be invoked automatically for each method's call.

Comment: Cant you just throw and catch exceptions? Would you consider using them?

Comment: Thus I must to wrap all invocations into try{}catch{}. It not suits me. And what if in some case I don't want to check error?

Comment: I need something like implemented in CodeContracts ([ContractInvariantMethod] private void ObjectInvariant(){}). But this invoked only after method execution

Comment: You could have an `out` `List` parameter on your method instead of one global `IList`. This way you can maintain the exception list between method calls.

Comment: This way you can also get rid of your `HasErrors` property and use a simple `if(myExceptionsList.Any())` instead.

Comment: @JamieDixon It makes me to define IList for out parameter for method call. Or in this case I should overload every methods. I need something that I would wrote just ones, and it would work for all future methods in this class.

Comment: seems like bad design to me, maybe think about defining a Result object that contains IsSuccess and the ListExceptions and return that from your method. Without knowing the full context, maintaining state simply for exception handling seems unwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another tool you could look into is PostSharp. PostSharp is an AOP frawework that allows you to define custom aspects (attributes).

You'll be interested in [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect.htm). Something like below should do the trick. args.Instance will be "the instance on which the method is being executed"

```
public class ClearListPrecondition : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        MyService service = args.Instance as MyService;
        if (service == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
              "This aspect can only execute on types of MyService");
        }

        service.ExList.Clear();
        base.OnEntry(args);
    }
}
```

You would then decorate your service methods with this aspect:

```
[ClearListPrecondition]
public void MyMethod()
{
}
```

If you choose to take the path of AOP for such a trivial task, I strongly recommend you re-thinking your design.

Firstly, throwing exceptions should be preferred, but if you insist, you could return a result from your method.

E.g.

```
public MethodResult MyMethod()
{
    ....
     if(errorHasOccured)
     {
          return new MethodResult() {Exceptions = exception};
     }
    ....
     return new MethodResult() {ResultOfMethod = ...};
}

public class MethodResult
{
   public IList<Exception> Exceptions {get; set;}
   public bool HasErrors { get { return ExList.Count > 0; } } 
   public string ResultOfMethod {get;set;}

}
```

Your consumers can check the result of a method call:

```
var service = new MyService();

var result1 = service.MyMethod();

if(result1.HasErrors)
{
    // - do some logic
}

var result2 = service.MyMethod();

if(result2.HasErrors) 
{
    // - do some logic
}
```

This removes the need to reset the state of your service as it becomes stateless (and therefore threadsafe)